# Generating a GPG key for git tagging

Tags: git, gnupg

I'm trying to create signed tags in GitHub using the git command line. I generated a GPG key with a (sample) username `Full Name (skytreader) <fullname@gmail.com>`. Having done that, I try to create a [signed tag](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Signing-Your-Work). However I get the following error:

```
gpg: skipped "full <fullname@gmail.com>": secret key not available
gpg: signing failed: secret key not available
error: gpg failed to sign the data
error: unable to sign the tag
```

I figure that I just need to create another key with the indicated username. But then, entering the name "full", `gpg` complains that my name should be at least 5 characters long.

How do I use this key with git?

Do I change the username git uses for signing my tags with GPG so that I get a real name at least 5 chars long?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The committer name is located in your `~/.gitconfig` file. Change that entry to a real name (which is how you want to be committing, anyway). You can edit the file in your favorite editor, or just issue:

```
git config --global user.name "<name>"
```

Comment: One more. Is it possible to include the "(skytreader)" part in my gitconfig (so I don't have to generate another GPG key)?

Comment: It can be anything you want. In fact, you can use the `-u` or `--local-user` flags to specify a specific `<key-id>` (it can also be set globally with `git config --global user.signingkey <gpg-key-id>`.

Answer (score 45):

First you need check if there is a gpg key for your ID.

```
$ gpg --list-key
```

If you have should appear something like this:

> 1. pub   2048R/6AB3587A 2013-05-23
> 2. uid   xxx (gpg for xxx)
> 3. sub   2048R/64CB327A 2013-05-23

If there is no gpg key. You should create

```
$ gpg --gen-key
```

Next you have this output:

> gpg (GnuPG) 2.0.14; Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>   This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
>   There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
>
> Please select what kind of key you want:
>
> 1. (1) RSA and RSA (default)
> 2. (2) DSA and Elgamal
> 3. (3) DSA (sign only)
> 4. (4) RSA (sign only)
>
> Your selection? RSA keys may be between 1024 and 4096 bits long. What keysize do you want? (2048)
>   Requested keysize is 2048 bits
>   Please
>   specify how long the key should be valid.
>
> ```
>          0 = key does not expire
>       <n>  = key expires in n days
>       <n>w = key expires in n weeks
>       <n>m = key expires in n months
>       <n>y = key expires in n years
> ```
>
> Key is valid for? (0)
>      Key does not expire at all
>      Is this correct? (y/N) y
>
> ```
> GnuPG needs to construct a user ID to identify your key.
>
> Real name: xxx
> Email address: xxx@example.com
> Comment: gpg for xxx
>
> You selected this USER-ID:
>     "xxx(gpg for xxx) <xxx@example.com>"
>
> Change (N)ame, (C)omment, (E)mail or (O)kay/(Q)uit? O
> You need a Passphrase to protect your secret key.
>
> can't connect to `/xxx/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent': No such file or directory
> We need to generate a lot of random bytes. It is a good idea to perform
> some other action (type on the keyboard, move the mouse, utilize the
> disks) during the prime generation; this gives the random number
> generator a better chance to gain enough entropy.
> ```

Comment: I left the comment field blank to get this working for me since I didn't have that matching in my gitconfig.

Answer (score 9):

If you have a key already generated, you can tell git to use that specific key without worrying about matching between your git user ID (name+email) and the GPG key's ID. You should have your git `user.email` match one of the emails on your GPG key for your signed tags or commits to be useful to other users, though.

To set the key for global use on your computer, set your git global config with:

```
git config --global user.signingkey 6AB3587A
```

Or, you can set the `user.signingkey` for only the current repository you're in with:

```
git config user.signingkey 6AB3587A
```

Comment: i prefer `git config --local user.signingkey 6AB3587A` since if it's on a public computer/server.